I am having an issue when copying from MS Project to Excel
I am having an issue when copying from MS Project to Excel.
The code randomly debugs with the error

Runtime error '1004': PasteSpecial method of Range class fail

I click resume and the code continues like there was no fault.
This can happen on any random PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues line or sometimes not at all
Anybody seen this before?
    Sub SS_Update_Workbook()
    
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        Dim WB1 As Workbook
        Dim WS1 As Worksheet
        Dim Tbl As ListObject
        Dim PrjApp As Object
    
        Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
        Set WS1 = WB1.Worksheets("SETUP SHEET")
        Set Tbl = WS1.ListObjects("MSP_DATA")
    
        ' Check if Project is open
        On Error Resume Next
        Set PrjApp = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0
    
        ' If MS Project is not open, alert the user
        If PrjApp Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "You Need to Open MS Project", vbCritical
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    
        ' Set up MSP Project chart columns
        With PrjApp
            .ViewApply Name:="MSP Data"
            .OutlineShowAllTasks
            .FilterClear
        End With
    
        ' Filter Flag 1 Include In Report
        With PrjApp
            .FilterEdit Name:="Test1", Taskfilter:=True, Create:=True, OverWriteExisting:=False, FieldName:="Flag1", _
                        Test:="equals", Value:="Yes", ShowInMenu:=False, showsummarytasks:=True
            .FilterApply Name:="Test1"
        End With
    
        ' Copy the project columns and paste into Excel
        PrjApp.SelectTaskColumn Column:="Baseline Duration"
        PrjApp.EditCopy
        WS1.Range("C9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
        PrjApp.SelectTaskColumn Column:="% Complete"
        PrjApp.EditCopy
        WS1.Range("D9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
        PrjApp.SelectTaskColumn Column:="Actual Work"
        PrjApp.EditCopy
        WS1.Range("E9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
        PrjApp.SelectTaskColumn Column:="Remaining Work"
        PrjApp.EditCopy
        WS1.Range("L9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
        ' Reset Excel view and enable alerts/screen updating
        WS1.Select
        WS1.Range("A1").Select
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    End Sub

Don't know how to fix

Bill, Greetings :-)
Okay, let's try it from the Excel perspective. I tweaked your code to work directly with Project's objects. Herewith is the result. No need to set the Project view or create a filter for Flag1. Note: you will need to set a reference to the Project Object Library.
Yeah, I know, it doesn't really answer your question as to why your code is "unstable", but it does give you something that will work reliably. If someone else jumps in with the reason your original code is unreliable, then give them the win.
Sub SS_Update_Workbook()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim xlRange As Range
Dim Tbl As ListObject
Dim PrjApp As Object
Dim t As Task
Dim i As Integer

Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set WS1 = WB1.Worksheets("SETUP SHEET")
'Set Tbl = WS1.ListObjects("MSP_DATA")

' Check if Project is open
On Error Resume Next
Set PrjApp = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

' If MS Project is not open, alert the user
If PrjApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "You Need to Open MS Project", vbCritical
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
End If

Set xlRange = WS1.Range("C9")
i = 0
For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
    If t.Flag1 = True Then
        xlRange.Offset(i, 0).Value = t.BaselineDuration /(ActiveProject.HoursPerDay * 60)
        xlRange.Offset(i, 1).Value = t.PercentComplete / 100
        xlRange.Offset(i, 2).Value = t.ActualWork / 60
        xlRange.Offset(i, 9).Value = t.RemainingWork / 60
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next t


' Reset Excel view and enable alerts/screen updating
WS1.Select
WS1.Range("A1").Select

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

